# Windows Javascript app - run in background and set focus on event

Tags: javascript, windows-8.1

I have chat application which, while in browser, when recieves new message, it thrown alert to let user know that there is a new message. Now, I'm trying to port the webpage to Windows 8 javascript app.

Is there any way to continue new message check (I'm using js to php long poll) and let user know somehow (some kind of popup,...) when there is a new message?

Comment: Any reason not to use a push notification?

Comment: Good idea. Do you know about any good tutorial to begin with (I'm new to windows 8 js apps, I never used push notifications before)?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465460.aspx

Comment: Sorry to say that, but it sounds too complicated. Isn't there any simple thing like window.showMessage('New message recieved')?

Comment: Oh, so all you need is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779727.aspx ?